# Cassandra Datastax Driver Tuning - more connections or more requests per connection?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to tune Cassandra because I keep getting this error:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: Timed out waiting for server response
```

But I'm not sure whether I should increase the number of connections I have per host or increase the number of requests per connection in the datastax driver.

In general, what is the best way to determine if adding more connections is better or adding more requests per connection?

Comment: what is the query you are executing ?

Comment: It's a SELECT ... WHERE ... LIMIT 1

Comment: Is it contains any in query ?

Comment: The majority of queries are like SELECT * WHERE ... LIMIT 1

Comment: Did you try to debug for which query you are getting this timeout error ?

Comment: It happens to all my read queries at some point. All my read queries follow the SELECT * WHERE ... LIMIT 1.